# Is it necessary to validate data going into a result class?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

In my library I have a class that does some processing, and the return of this `process()` method is a `Result` class.

For example,

```
class Result {
    protected $data1;
    protected $data2;
    public function __construct($data1, $data2) {
        $this->data1 = $data1;
        $this->data2 = $data2;
    }
    // Some getters that use $data1 and $data2
}
```

This `Result` class has some getters on it that process `$data1` and `$data2` for their returns.

Now, for these getters to work `$data1` and `$data2` will need to be of a certain format, e.g. string, multi-dimensional array, etc.

My processing class will always instantiate `Result` correctly, but **should I still be validating the data going into `Result` anyway**?

If invalid data is injected and a particular method is run, then a PHP error will occur, which is obviously bad. But that will only happen if someone physically instantiates the `Result` class with erroneous data.

I just don't want to add validation, and therefore more overhead, when I don't believe it's actually required.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you trust the source of the data? If so, then don't worry about validation.

On the other hand, if this data comes from an untrusted source — a prime example: user-provided data from a web page — then yes, you absolutely should validate the input.

Comment: I think the question hints at the result class being instantiated from code, without user input.

Comment: As I said, the `Result` class is only ever instantiated by *my* code after the data has gone through some extensive validation and processing anyway, so at the point it's injected into the `Result` it can be trusted. The only way it could be invalid is someone instantiating `Result` themselves directly outside of this process, which if they do that, they're breaking usage anyway. So I'm inclined to not have validation repeated.

Comment: @Stephen: then there's your answer.

Comment: Sound. Just needed a sanity check. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should theoretically. If this would be a question asked to you in classroom the answer should be yes, you never know which corner cases occur, or maybe someone else has to maintain the application you create and can possibly break the application.

However, in practice your customer and employer would rather see working software then (for them at least) a lot of lines of code that never really does anything. I would just write it on my to do list and do something of higher priority.

Comment: I completely agree. However, let me just say classes should perform the minimum validation required to ensure they are working with data that won't explode. I.e., you are expecting an array, check if it's an array, otherwise throw an exception. There generally isn't the same "validation scheme" required at this level, just basic sanity checks most likely.